# Help Understanding Nash Equilibrium and Bivariate Matrices.

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium

I have the following 2 player payoff bi-variate matrix

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0,1 & 1,0 & 0,0 & 1,3 \\
        1,1 & 2,3 & 2,2 & 2,3 \\
        0,3 & 0,0 & 1,3 & 3,3 \\
        1,0 & 0,0 & 0,0 & 1,4 \\
        \end{matrix}
$$

I want to mark all equilibria in this matrix, and so I marked it as such:

$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0,1 & 1^*,0 & 0,0 & 1^*,3^* \\
        1,1 & 2^*,3^* & 2^*,2 & 2^*,3^* \\
        0,3^* & 0,0 & 1,3^* & 3^*,3^* \\
        1^*,0 & 0,0 & 0,0 & 1^*,4^* \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
And so I claim that the equilibria are at points (1,3)$R_1C_4$, (2,3)$R_2C_2$, (2,3)$R_2C_4$, (3,3)$R_3C_4$, and finally (1,4)$R_4C_4$

However, upon review of my answer, my notes claim that the following are the markings of the equilibria:
$$
        \begin{matrix}
        0,1 & 1,0 & 0,0 & 1,3^* \\
        1^*,1 & 2^*,3^* & 2^*,2 & 2,3^* \\
        0,3^* & 0,0 & 1,3^* & 3^*,3^* \\
        1^*,0 & 0,0 & 0,0 & 1,4^* \\
        \end{matrix}
$$
And so the equilibria are at points (2,3)$R_2C_2$ and (3,3)$R_3C_4$. Why?

As a side note, the notes also claim that the Pareto optimal payoffs are (3,3) and (1,4)

Any help as to why the results are the way they are is much appreciated!

Comment: What does this have to do with Nash bargaining?

Comment: @MichaelGreinecker To be honest, I'm not sure myself, other than that this problem is listed under the 'Nash Bargaining' section of the text

Comment: If there is a more specific or different tag I should be using, please suggest it and I'll change it.

Comment: The tags are fine, this is about Nash equilibrium. But the title is misleading, it has nothing to with [Nash's bargaining solution](http://faculty.georgetown.edu/la2/Bargaining.pdf).

Comment: Fantastic source, thank you! I would +1 that but I do not have the reputation to do unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customarily, the first payoff refers to the Row player and the second payoff to the Column player. Thus, when you search for the best replies of the Row player, you fix a column and look which row yields the highest payoff among the *first* element of each payoff pair. Similarly for the Column player. This gives you the second construction. (You searched across columns for the Row player and across rows for the Column player.)